# Exception while running docker-compose up with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, daphne

To setup secure websocket in Django Rest Framework, I added Daphne to docker-compose.yml as follows

```
  daphne:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: 'sh -c "daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000  apps.asgi:application"'
    restart: always
```

When I bring the docker-compose up, I'm seeing the following error. If I remove the daphne entry from docker-compose.yml, this error does not happen.  I was able to successfully build the compose earlier.

```
daphne_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
daphne_1   |     httplib_response = self._make_request(
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
daphne_1   |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
daphne_1   |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
daphne_1   |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
daphne_1   |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
daphne_1   |     self.send(msg)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
daphne_1   |     self.connect()
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
daphne_1   |     sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
daphne_1   | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
daphne_1   |     resp = conn.urlopen(
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
daphne_1   |     retries = retries.increment(
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
daphne_1   |     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
daphne_1   |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
daphne_1   |     httplib_response = self._make_request(
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
daphne_1   |     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
daphne_1   |     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
daphne_1   |     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
daphne_1   |     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
daphne_1   |     self.send(msg)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
daphne_1   |     self.connect()
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
daphne_1   |     sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
daphne_1   | urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
daphne_1   |     return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
daphne_1   |     return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
daphne_1   |     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
daphne_1   |     return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
daphne_1   |     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
daphne_1   |     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
daphne_1   |     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
daphne_1   |     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
daphne_1   | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
daphne_1   |
daphne_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
daphne_1   |     sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 170, in entrypoint
daphne_1   |     cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 232, in run
daphne_1   |     application = import_by_path(args.application)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
daphne_1   |     target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
daphne_1   |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
daphne_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
daphne_1   |   File "/app/./apps/asgi.py", line 14, in <module>
daphne_1   |     django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/asgi.py", line 12, in get_asgi_application
daphne_1   |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
daphne_1   |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
daphne_1   |     app_config.ready()
daphne_1   |   File "/app/./apps/environments/apps.py", line 8, in ready
daphne_1   |     from . import signals
daphne_1   |   File "/app/./apps/environments/signals.py", line 6, in <module>
daphne_1   |     from apps.cloud.tasks import remove_periodic_tasks
daphne_1   |   File "/app/./apps/cloud/tasks.py", line 21, in <module>
daphne_1   |     from apps.cloud.utils import (
daphne_1   |   File "/app/./apps/cloud/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
daphne_1   |     client: DockerClient = docker.from_env()
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 96, in from_env
daphne_1   |     return cls(
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 45, in __init__
daphne_1   |     self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
daphne_1   |     self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
daphne_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
daphne_1   |     raise DockerException(
daphne_1   | docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the socket entry in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```